# Qual a função de AsReadOnly() em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Estou estudando `List` em C#, pesquisei na internet mas mesmo assim não entendi como funciona.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("Maria");
list.Add("Lucas");
list.Add("Renata");
list.Add("Yara");
list.Add("Josias");
list.Add("Morten Granau");
list.Add("Phaxe")

IList<string> auxiliar = list.AsReadOnly();
```

O que essa função faz `AsReadOnly()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sua função é criar um objeto ([`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) que garanta o contrato que o objeto original não será alterado, desta forma você pode passar para métodos, possivelmente em outro contexto de execução (outra *thread*) e será garantido que ele será usado só como leitura. Portanto é uma forma mais semântica e mais segura de usar  o objeto que deseja que nesse contexto seja imutável.

Note que ele não faz cópia alguma, não tem um processamento real, apenas mantém um objeto que é do mesmo tipo do original sem permitir as alterações no seu conteúdo. Em geral só faz sentido se for passar para outro método.

Todo o .NET foi modificado para aceitar este tipo de objeto e dar mais garantias, e seus códigos deveriam fazer o mesmo, afinal, fica mais seguro em todos os sentidos e por até ser mais performático, especialmente ajuda em ambientes concorrentes.

Se quer que o objeto original seja imutável sempre deve usar um [`ImmutableList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que faz parte de uma coleção de objetos que as pessoas desconhecem e devem ser escolhidos se não precisa fazer alterações nele. Infelizmente a maioria dos programadores não conhecem as novidades do C# e do .NET e continuam fazendo como era 15 anos atrás (por isso tenho uma palestra e planejo um dia ter um livro sobre C# Moderno).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não faz mais sentido fazer da forma como fez, faça assim:

```
var list = new List<string> { "Maria", "Lucas", "Renata", "Yara", "Josias", "Morten Granau""Morten Granau", "Phaxe" };
Metodo(list.AsReadOnly());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AsReadOnly.cs).

Considerando que a assinatura deste método seja mais ou menos `Metodo(ReadOnlyCollection lista)`.

Em muitos casos o uso de um [`IReadOnlyCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pode ser suficiente.

Answer (score 7):

Ele retorna uma classe chamada `ReadOnlyCollection`. Com isto, você garante que a coleção não sofrerá alterações, ela realmente será apenas leitura.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(2);
myList.Add(3);
myList.Add(4);
myList.Add(5);

var myListReadOnly = myList.AsReadOnly();
myListReadOnly[0] = 1;// não pode fazer isto
myListReadOnly.Add(1); // não pode fazer isto
```

No exempo que você colocou

```
IList<string> auxiliar = list.AsReadOnly();
```

Não tem sentido porque você está criando um `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` porém convertendo novamente para um `IList<T>`, ou seja, copiando uma lista que pode ser alterada. Esta conversão é possível porque `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` também implementa `IList<T>`
O certo seria:

```
var auxiliar = list.AsReadOnly();
```

Seria implícito o uso da classe ReadOnlyCollection. Ou você pode fazê-lo de forma explícita:

```
IReadOnlyList<string> auxiliar = list.AsReadOnly();
```

Um detalhe importante é que `ReadOnlyCollection` é apenas um wrapper que não expõe os métodos de modificação da coleção mas se alguma alteração for feita na lista original, estas mesmas alterações serão refletidas nesta lista também.